# To make endless row on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Very simple question.

How do you make endless row on spreadsheet? Like Excel.

I have this problem when I use google sheet to scan barcodes.

When rows reached 1000, I need to add more manually.

But sometimes I forget, then I keep scanning.

After that I check my sheet, I missed a lot of input but I don't remember which barcode was the last one, so I have to do them all over again after increasing the rows.

If google sheets has the infinite rows like Excel, I won't have to worry about it no more.

Do you guys have any solutions on this?

Comment: gs has only limited amout of rows

Comment: @player0 do you have a work around solution?

Comment: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603 - The limit for Google Sheets is 5 million cells. How is the bar code scanner inputting the information? Via Apps Script?

Comment: @iansedano Barcode scanners, in my experience, are essentially keyboard devices (if it's a USB device). They scan the code, type out the data, and press Enter. Most likely a script will have to detect the current cell and move it over one column. Another option would be to use a Google Doc and have it keep entering there, then transfer the results.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz interesting, thanks. That approach could work if BahetiyaYiliyaer can confirm it acts like a USB keyboard?

Comment: @iansedano Yes. The barcode scanner acts like a USB keyboard. It scans the barcode, input on one cell and then input ENTER to switch to next row of the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use Apps Script to Make Your Sheet Dynamic

With Apps Script, you can write a function to detect how many cells are between the data inserted and the end of the spreadsheet, and add rows if they are too close.

```js
function addRowsIfCloseToEnd() {

  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // INPUT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  let maxRow = sheet.getMaxRows()
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

  // In this example, when the values are 100 rows
  // from the end of the sheet, it will add 100 rows
  // to the end. Change this to your liking.
  if (maxRow - lastRow < 100) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRow, 100)
  }
}
```

In this example, the function checks when values are less than 100 rows from the end of the spreadsheet, and if it is, it will add 100 extra rows to the sheet.

You should adjust these numbers to suit your workflow, I don't know how many bar codes you scan or how quickly.

You have two options for how to trigger this:

#### onEdit

This is a simple trigger designed to run a function every single time there is an edit on the sheet. You can call the previous function like this:

```js
function onEdit() {
  addRowsIfCloseToEnd()
}
```

If you have authorized your script, then this should run every time you make an edit:

[image]

In this example I only add 10 rows every time, to demonstrate.

#### Time-based trigger

Depending on how many barcodes you scan and how quickly, you may not want this function to run every single time you scan a barcode, in which case you can make a trigger to run every 5 minutes for example:

```js
function createClockTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("addRowsIfCloseToEnd")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
}
```

#### References

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive solution. It worked perfectly for me. I have one more request, please help me. Is it possible to apply this function to the whole spreadsheet?

Comment: No problem, you should be able to replace this line `let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");` with `let sheet = file.getActiveSheet();`